# How can I update the Ubuntu SDK preview from the Qt 5 Beta PPA to the Qt 5 Release PPA

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, beta, ubuntu-sdk

When the [Ubuntu SDK preview](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) was announced on the 2nd of January, it was based on the Qt 5 Beta release (as Qt 5 had not yet been released and packaged for Ubuntu). At some point, the Qt 5 release was packaged on a separate PPA and the Ubuntu SDK migrated to be based on the contents of that PPA.

New installs work fine as described on the [Ubuntu SDK installation instructions](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/), but I'd like to know how those of us who installed it on release day on the 2nd can migrate to the latest version of the SDK, as the change of PPAs requires a manual upgrade.

This seems to be related to reports of folks who get the `"error importing Ubuntu.Components"` message when upgrading the SDK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

During the migration from the Qt 5 Beta to the Qt 5 Release, the packaging changed significantly. This means upgrading the SDK is not a trivial task such as `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and a few manual steps are necessary.

## Migration: from the Qt 5 Beta 1 to Qt 5.0

1. Open the `~/.bashrc` file

   `$ gedit ~/.bashrc`
2. Remove the `'export PATH=/opt/qt5/bin:$PATH'` line from the `~/.bashrc` file
3. Uninstall Qt Creator temporarily

   `$ sudo apt-get remove qtcreator qt4-qmlviewer`
4. Purge the Qt 5 Beta 1 PPA

   `$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

   `$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta1`
5. Install the Ubuntu SDK preview

   `$ sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper && sudo apt-get update  && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk notepad-qml`
6. Test that the Component Showcase app can be executed:

   `$ qmlscene /usr/lib/qt-components-ubuntu/demos/ComponentShowcase.qml`

Comment: I followed the steps above and now I'm getting the following errors when executing the ComponentShowcase demo: 

... module "Ubuntu.Components" is not installed ... module "QtQuick" is not installed ...

Comment: It seems that this was an bug that was fixed by the last update of the ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper PPA.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue as Avedo, but it doesn't seem to be fixed by updating. :(

Answer (score 3):

In case the step 4. does not remove all the packages from the qt5-beta1 PPA the line helped me to clean up was this:

`$ grep ^Package: /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net*sdk*Packages /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net*qt5-beta1*Packages |awk '{print $2}'|xargs sudo apt-get -y remove`

You can execute the same command and replace the "apt-get -y remove" to "sudo dpkg --purge" to purge the possible leftovers after apt-get.

Answer (score 2):

@sil: `sudo apt-get install qt-components-ubuntu` will install the missing components.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

In case you're unlucky (like me) to find after the Ubuntu SDK installation that:

- it lacks the SQLITE Qt plugin (preventing the Notepad QML example from running)
- it lacks the LocalStorage QML plugin (same effect as above)
- Qt Creator installed with the SDK lacks Assistant help
- your default (not installed in `/opt` or `~/`) Qt4 dev environment is ruined (they warned you though, when you added the PPA)

You can get away by installing the Qt5.0.0 (not 5.0.1) via the ([.run file](http://releases.qt-project.org/qt5/5.0.0/qt-linux-opensource-5.0.0-x86-offline.run)) and then copying the contents of `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/` to `/home/your-name-here/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/gcc/qml`.

After that, you will be able to work with your Ubuntu projects (either launching from QML or via a C++ wrapper) from the Qt Creator bundled with Qt you installed from the run file (there will be no content-assistance for Ubuntu QML items, though).

I assume that setting paths (LD_LIBRARY_PATH et al) properly will allow the compiled apps to be run from the command-line, but haver not tried that, as the Qt5 installed with Ubuntu SDK is now always on my path, and I'm a Linux noob :)

If you know how one can get the contents of `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/` without actually installing the components, please update this answer.

Hopefully, this is helpful to someone.

Comment: The SDK Preview keeps improving at great paces, so if you find any issues, please do report them at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+filebug - the particular issue you're mentioning is a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1119730), which can be worked around by simply installing the missing packages manually (e.g. `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin`)

Comment: And in general, I'd always recommend to install packaged versions of software, which will save you having to deal with things such as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or even have to know what it means). And you get automatic updates of the software! :)

Comment: @DavidPlanella ok, many thanks for the hints. I'd still prefer to keep frameworks manually installed to separate dirs (may be there's a Slackware guy somewhere in me, who knows? :)

Comment: ...and `sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-sqlite` fixes the second issue, it appears.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with LocalStorage, but then I installed qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin as David Planella said.
After that I got error that I don't have LocalStorage installed on line

```
import LocalStorage 2.0
```

and then I changed it to

```
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
```

and it works now.